# XSL Web Page Displaying in Quirks Mode

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, xslt, quirks-mode

I'm developing a website using XSL and HTML, CSS and jQuery.. The application is displaying perfectly in Firefox, however in IE8 and 9, it appears to be running in Quirks Mode.

I've checked all my HTML, and 100% confident its clean, but not too certain about the XSL as that was written 8-9years ago.

Here are a sample of the headers in my .XSL files:

output.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
```

Address:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [

  <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">

]>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
```

Product:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well what matters is not the root element of the stylesheet, rather the use of the `xsl:output`, make sure you have e.g.

```
<xsl:output
  method="html"
  version="4.01"
  doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
  indent="yes"/>
```

to have MSXML, the XSLT processor that IE uses, output a `DOCTYPE` in the result HTML that puts IE in standards mode.

Comment: Ive checked my .XSL files and cannot find any references to a <xsl:output/> tag... Where should this be placed?

Comment: As a child element of the root element e.g. `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"><xsl:output .../>...</xsl:styleheet>`.