# How to adjust this XSL script to prevent Quirks Mode?

Tags: xslt-1.0, doctype, webview2, quirks-mode

I started developing my software 20 years ago. Back then I was using Expression Web Editor to build my template HTML files. Today I noticed a message about my page being in Quirks Mode. I looked it up and can see that it is concerning the `DOCTYPE` element.

I am using an XSL transformation sheet with a WebView2 browser control:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
      doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
      doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
```

How should this be defined now then to switch off Quirks Mode?

---

The problem is, if I change it to:

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
```

Then I get no `DOCTYPE` declaration, whereas I really want to see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I looked up [`xsl:output`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_output.asp) and it does not seem to show this scenario.

Looks like this might be a limitation of needing to use XSLT-1 ([XSL Web Page Displaying in Quirks Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22009287/2287576)).

Comment: I think it's described here, but my knowledge on XSLT is limited, see: [If you serve your page as XHTML using the application/xhtml+xml MIME type in the Content-Type HTTP header, you do not need a DOCTYPE to enable standards mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode#xhtml)

Comment: More help might b found here (the first error on): [validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftech.brookes.ac.uk%2Fwebmsc%2Fp00772%2Fxslt1_b%2Fslide5.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: When generating HTML from XSLT 1, set the system property to [`about:legacy-compat`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/urls-and-fetching.html#about:legacy-compat) and omit the public property.

Comment: @Alohci Can you please show me a worked sample?